# objective-c(iPhone)で"sysctl -a"と同等の値を表示させたい。

Tags: ios, objective-c

objective-cかつiPhoneにて、sysctl -aに該当する現在利用できる全ての値を取得したいと考えております。

何か良い方法はございませんでしょうか。

Comment: sysctrlのソースは[ここ](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-496/sysctl.tproj/sysctl.c)にあるので、そのまま使うか必要な部分だけコピペすればいけると思います。

Answer (score -1):

iOSとOS XのSDKでは[sysctl()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sysctl.3.html)関数を使う